# Methods showTimePicker with restrictions

Tags: flutter

How do I restrict own specified times of the time picker **(showTimePicker)** in flutter?
I don't want that someone is able to select inappropriate times.

How can I handle this? Are there any examples?

By the way is there a similar way for the **showDatePicker** method only for disabling dates?

Thank you all so much in advanced !!

Comment: If you have limited times you should use a DropDown instead, you can also set an interval in the DatePicker if that is what you want, however if you want only specific limited dates as well, then I believe it is way better done using a DropDown.

Comment: Currently these are features are not available with existing `showTimePicker` and `showDatePicker`. You can simple look into the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart) and replicate one with your required features.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this temporal solution
[time_picker_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/time_picker_widget)

[DEMO](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5c32e473c8c1c9687966453d0dcf42de?)

It is a custom showTimePicker to allow you set a selectableTimePredicate like you do in showDatePicker.

[image]

```dart
showCustomTimePicker(
    context: context,
    // It is a must if you provide selectableTimePredicate
    onFailValidation: (context) => print('Unavailable selection'),
    initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 2, minute: 0),
    selectableTimePredicate: (time) =>
        time.hour > 1 &&
        time.hour < 14 &&
        time.minute % 10 == 0).then((time) =>
    setState(() => selectedTime = time?.format(context)))
```

Comment: Are you still maintaining this? The online Demo isn't working.