# How to select only hour from timer picker flutter

Tags: flutter, date, dart, datepicker

right now I am doing one task where I want to make that user can select the only hours from the timer picker. But I am not able to find any solution. If anyone have a solution, then please let me know.

Example: 12:00

I want to make that user can select the only hour from time picker won't be able to see the minute picker

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this widget https://pub.dev/packages/time_picker_widget
Then limit the time as sugested in the awsnser here: [Methods showTimePicker with restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700890/methods-showtimepicker-with-restrictions)

However you might just use a `TextField` with `keyboardType: TextInputType.number`, because in general this restricted time picker might not be what the user expects